# Multiples inserts in core data

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I have a lot information to repopulate my database, that's how I do:

```
let notaryFeeGrid = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "NotaryFeeGrid", into: context) as! NotaryFeeGrid

notaryFeeGrid.id = 0
notaryFeeGrid.notaryLoansAmount = 1000
notaryFeeGrid.notaryFeeAmount = 510

context.insert(notaryFeeGrid)


let notaryFeeGrid2 = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "NotaryFeeGrid", into: context) as! NotaryFeeGrid

notaryFeeGrid2.id = 0
notaryFeeGrid2.notaryLoansAmount = 3000
notaryFeeGrid2.notaryFeeAmount = 530

context.insert(notaryFeeGrid2)

let notaryFeeGrid3 = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "NotaryFeeGrid", into: context) as! NotaryFeeGrid

notaryFeeGrid3.id = 0
notaryFeeGrid3.notaryLoansAmount = 5000
notaryFeeGrid3.notaryFeeAmount = 570

context.insert(notaryFeeGrid3)
```

It's a little part of the full code, how can I minimize this ?

Comment: Make a function for all of your repeating code. Then for each 'insert', call your function.

Comment: @AgRizzo It is possible to do better with something like an array ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this...... Create a array of Notary Items..

**Update:**

```
func addNotary(_ context : NSManagedObjectContext,_ notaryArray: Array) -> Bool {

    for index in 0...notaryArray.count - 1
    {
        let notary : Dictionary = notaryArray[index] as! Dictionary
        let notaryFeeGrid = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "NotaryFeeGrid", into: context) as! NotaryFeeGrid

        notaryFeeGrid.id = notary["id"]
        notaryFeeGrid.notaryLoansAmount = notary["notaryLoansAmount"]
        notaryFeeGrid.notaryFeeAmount = notary["notaryFeeAmount"]
    }

    var error: NSError?
    let success = context.save(&error)
    if !success {
        print("Save failed")
    }
}
```